# Why is certutil returns a self signed error?

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, x509, mitmproxy

I'd like to make cpp code that inserts a certificate file to the root trusted ca list. The program should run on windows so, I tried to use:

```
certutil -importpfx mitmproxy-cert-ca.p12.
```

I ran it as admin, but unfortunately it returns a self signed certificate error.

Obviously mitmproxy's certificate must be self signed, so I'm not sure why it's complaining.

Also, the password to pass for this certificate is a blank password, but if I try to add it as a parameter at the command - it didn't work when I tried to pass: `-p ""`

If someone could tell me how I can solve this issue, it'll be fantastic.

One last thing, is some other  way to do it in cpp?

Comment: Wait, it's a pkcs12 certificate with the private key attached ? Um... you import a self-signed CA *public* certificate to a trusted root certificate store (TRCS), using the [windows certificate APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/cryptography-functions#certificate-and-certificate-store-functions) (which are *not* trivial in their own right). Further, only a system account can update the computer TRCS; regular users will modify the per-user TRCS (theirs).

Comment: It's mitmproxy's pkcs12 certificate, in their document they specify how to add the certificate automatically to TRCS but it still returns self signed error for some reason:https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/

Comment: What is `cpp code`? Do you mean `C++`? Why is the question tagged with `powershell`?

Comment: `certutil` is a legacy command line util, the Powershell equivalent is [Import-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate).

Comment: @JamesC. I disagree that `certutil` is legacy command. It is fully supported and not superseded by PowerShell. PowerShell natively (via cmdlets) covers less than 1% of certutil functionality. Even `Import-PfxCertificate` implements only a subset of `certutil -importpfx` functionality.

Comment: @M.Boggio use `-f` switch: `certutil -f -importpfx root path\file.p12`.